# iPhone 7 Sim Switching, Account Switching or just Normal Domain Traffic?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, dns, sim

I think there is some funny business going on with one of the devices in my house.

I'm not sure if the person is changing into between iCloud Accounts on the same device, or switching Sims or using multiple Sims on an iPhone 7 or not? It just seems strange and I'm trying to get to the bottom of it.

I'm seeing patterns like this below. I think some might be add networks but I'm seeing a lot of the certificate stuff. Here's an example in order.

6:18PM - ocsp.godaddy.com

6:18PM - ib.adnxs.com

6:18PM - prg.kargo.com

6:18PM - match.adsrvr.org

6:19PM - match.adsrvr.org

6:19PM - sync.mathtag.com

6:22PM - ocsp.apple.com

I see the ocsp domains a lot along with items like;

ocsp.digicert.com

sr.symcd.com

inet.ess.apple.com

Just wondering if any of the above will show up a lot if;

the device is being restarted

a new sim is being initiated

or if an apple id account is being switched between

Comment: What makes you believe that a device is being restarted, a new sim is being initiated, or an Apple ID account is being switched? Is your wireless network protected with a passcode? What security protocol are you using on your network? Can you see the local IP address for each of the entries on the list you posted?

Comment: I'm seeing this a lot and just wondering if it's the 'culprit' switching ids, turning off notification so they are not heard and don't come through when the phone is out in the open, etc.  

[Site allowed: init-p01md.apple.com] from source 192.168.1.9, Saturday, May 19,2018 09:05:31
[Site allowed: init.ess.apple.com] from source 192.168.1.9, Saturday, May 19,2018 09:05:31

Answer (score 1):

This looks like normal advertisement and certificate network traffic to me.

A SIM card swap, device restart, or Apple ID login wouldn't/shouldn't produce traffic to ad servers. A device restart might ping OCSPs ([Online Certificate Status Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol)), but it makes more sense for that to be checked by a browser when visiting a website.